# Perl/Sed: Delete a function that extends to multiple lines

Tags: perl, sed

I want to delete every call to a function `XYZ`. The problem is that this function might extend to multiple lines. E.g.

```
XYZ( "line 1",
     "line 2",
     "line 3" );
```

To simplify things, I have the assumption that `);` is only present at the end of the call.

I have tried `sed 's/XYZ(.*);//'` without success, though in `sed` the `.` character matches any char including newline. I am probably missing something with the new lines in `sed`.

Thank you

Comment: Please add the code you have tried. Try `/m` for multiline matching.

Comment: @Wordzilla That won't help. The `/m` modifier only allows `^` and `$` to match newlines.

Comment: I updated with the `sed` command tried so far

Comment: @TLP Thanks for the catch. `/s` matches multiline strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use address range as

```
sed '/^XYZ/, /);$/ d' inputFile
```

- `/^XYZ/` start address
- `/);$/` end address
- `d` delete command. Deltes line from pattern space in the address range provided

**Test**

```
$ cat input
XYZ( "line 1",
     "line 2",
     "line 3" );

hello world

XYZ( "line 1",
     "line 2",
     "line 3" );

$ sed '/^XYZ/, /);$/ d' input

hello world
```

**EDIT**

To take care of cases where the function occures in same line

```
$ sed '/^XYZ.*);$/d;  /^XYZ/, /);$/ d' input
```

**Test**

```
$ cat input
XYZ( "line 1",
     "line 2",
     "line 3" );
helo
XYZ( "line 1",     "line 2",     "line 3" );
hello world

$ sed '/^XYZ.*);$/d;  /^XYZ/, /);$/ d' input
helo
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I exclude functions like ABCXYZ from deletion?

Comment: All goes well, apart from a case: when XYZ is single line: `XYZ( blah );
ABC( bleh );`

also removes `ABC( bleh );`

Comment: @TsiftisKarampouzouklis That is tricky But solvable :) Check my edit. Hope it ok now

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -p0e 's!\bXYZ\(.*?\);!!gs' input
```

Testing:

```
XYZ( "line 1",
     "line 2",
     "line 3" );

hello world

XYZ( "line 1",
     "line 2",
     "line 3" );
   XYZ(aaaa); XYZ(aaaa);  aaa(aaaa);

abcXYZ( aaaa );
   XYZ(aaaa);
   XYZabc(aa);
```

output is:

```
hello world


     aaa(aaaa);

abcXYZ( aaaa );

   XYZabc(aa);
```